# How to write a config to source generate a mapper for IReadOnlyCollection using Mapster?

Tags: c#, collections, code-generation, mapster

How can I write a config to source generate a mapper from IReadOnlyCollection<POCO> to IReadOnlyCollection<DTO> using Mapster?

I have tried doing the following but it does not work.

```
public class MapsterConfiguration : IRegister
{
    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<IReadOnlyCollection<POCO>, IReadOnlyCollection<DTO>>()
            .GenerateMapper(MapType.Map | MapType.MapToTarget);
    }
}
```

but if I use IReadOnlyCollection as a property, it works

```
public class CollectionDTO
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<DTO> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

```
config.NewConfig<CollectionPOCO, CollectionDTO>()
                .GenerateMapper(MapType.Map | MapType.MapToTarget);
```

Comment: What is the error or symptom of the top code not working?

Comment: A file with mapping methods for the type IReadOnlyCollection<POCO> should be generated, but this does not happen.